# testing.postgresql command not found: initdb inside docker

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

Hi i'm trying to make a unittest with postgresql database that use sqlalchemy and alembic

Also im running it on docker postgresql

I'm following the docs of testing.postgresql([docs](https://pypi.org/project/testing.postgresql/)) to set up a temporary postgresql instance handle database testing and wrote the the following test:

```
def test_crawl_bds_obj(self):
    with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
        engine.create_engine(postgresql.url())
        result = crawl_bds_obj(1 ,'/ban-can-ho-chung-cu-duong-mai-chi-tho-phuong-an-phu-prj-the-sun-avenue/nh-chu-gap-mat-tien-t-q2-thuoc-du-tphcm-pr22171626')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'sell')
```

The crawl_bds_obj() basically save information from an URL and save it to the database using session.commit() and return the type data

When i tried to run the test it return the following error:

```
ERROR: test_crawl_bds_obj (tests.test_utils.TestUtils)
raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
RuntimeError: command not found: initdb
```

In the docs it said that "testing.postgresql.Postgresql executes initdb and postgres on instantiation. On deleting Postgresql object, it terminates PostgreSQL instance and removes temporary directory."

So why am i getting initdb error when i already installed testing.postgresql and had postgresql running on my docker?

**EDIT:**

I aslo had set my data path but it still return the same error

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:slim-jessie
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

docker-compose:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_DEFAULT_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DEFAULT_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_DEFAULT_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
       - ./data/pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT}:80"
    logging:
      driver: none
    restart: unless-stopped

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: "watchmedo auto-restart --recursive -p '*.py'"
    environment:
      - C_FORCE_ROOT=1
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - rabbit
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
      - postgres
```

> testing.postgresql.Postgresql(copy_data_from='data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data')

Answer (score 1):

you need to run this command as `postgresql` user not `root`, so you may try to run your commands using:

```
runuser -l  postgres -c 'command'
```

or

```
su -c "command" postgres
```

or add `USER postgres` to your `Dockerfile`

and check the requirments:

```
Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5
pg8000 1.10
```

**UPDATE**

To make `copy_data_from` works you should generate the folder first:

```
FROM python:slim-jessie
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN /PATH/TO/initdb -D myData -U postgres
```

and then add this:

```
pg = testing.postgresql.Postgresql(copy_data_from='myData')
```

Comment: but I already had POSTGRES_USER=postgres and set the password of it in the enviroment of postgres in docker-compose, do i need to add it again in my dockerfile ?

Comment: so right now i'm running "python -m unittest discover" in my current "worker"(main project container) not "postgres" container. do i need to change it to the postgres container ?

Comment: i added "USER postgres" to my dockerfile which run with the worker container, and restart my containers but it still has the error

Comment: Restart won't help you need to rebuild it

Comment: "Cannot start service worker: unable to find user postgres: no matching entries in passwd file" when i rebuild it, do i need anything else in the docker file ?

Comment: i had made an edit to my post with dockerfile and docker-compose code

Comment: is "/PATH/TO/initdb" the same as the path in my postgres volumes ?

Comment: to be sure login to your container and use `locate` or `find`to find the binary

Comment: i logged into my postgres /bin/bash with docker exec and used the "find . -name 'initdb'" go the path which is "./usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb" but somehow it got this error "Service 'worker' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c ./usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb -D myData -U postgres'" , did i find the wrong path ?

Comment: Remove the . From the path

Comment: rebuild and still "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb: not found"