# In testing.postgresql, cannot find initdb command inside Docker

Tags: python, postgresql, unit-testing, docker

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720546/testing-postgresql-command-not-found-initdb-inside-docker) that has the same problem but wasn't able to work for me. Basically, I'm trying to unittest `myproject` with `testing.postgresql` and i'm running it inside a docker container.

However, I get a `RuntimeError: command not found: initdb` when I run my command,

`docker-compose exec myproject python3 -m unittest`

This works in WSL but not inside docker.

Looks like it's not able to find initdb. Is it having conflict issues with the database created in docker-compose.yml or am I missing some lines inside the docker files?

I outline my test like example from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/testing.postgresql/):

```
class TestPostgresqlInteraction(unittest.TestCase):

    Postgresql = testing.postgresql.PostgresqlFactory(cache_initialized_db=True)

    with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
        engine = create_engine(postgresql.url())
        dbConn = psycopg2.connect(**postgresql.dsn())
        cursor = dbConn.cursor()
        def setUp(self):
            self.postgresql = self.Postgresql()

        def tearDown(self):
            self.postgresql.stop()

        def testMethod(self)
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**self.postgresql.dsn())
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            # execute cursor and do tests... 

        def tearDownModule(self):
            self.Postgresql.clear_cache()
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
    myproject:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./myproject/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - database
        volumes:
            - ./myproject:/code
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
    database:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./database/Dockerfile
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER_FILE: /secrets/dbUser.txt
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE: /secrets/dbPassword.txt
        ports:
            - "8765:5432"
        volumes:
            - otherdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

myproject/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.3-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    poppler-utils

ARG moduleDir=myproject

WORKDIR /code

COPY secrets/ /secrets

# COPY $moduleDir/myproject/ ./

COPY $moduleDir/requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

database/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:11.3

WORKDIR /secrets

COPY secrets/dbUser.txt dbUser.txt
COPY secrets/dbPassword.txt dbPassword.txt

RUN mkdir -p /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

COPY database/schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Traceback:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.testMyproject
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/code/tests/testmyProject.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TestPostgresqlInteraction(unittest.TestCase):
  File "/code/tests/testmyProject.py", line 46, in TestPostgresqlInteraction
    Postgresql = testing.postgresql.PostgresqlFactory(cache_initialized_db=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testing/common/database.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.cache = self.target_class(**settings_noautostart)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testing/common/database.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testing/postgresql.py", line 50, in initialize
    self.initdb = find_program('initdb', ['bin'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/testing/postgresql.py", line 144, in find_program
    raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
RuntimeError: command not found: initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `testing.postgresql` means that you will get new instance of PG prepared by the tool - as it is described in their [docs](https://pypi.org/project/testing.postgresql/). What you need to do is to point to that other docker. Simply use `psycopg` and connect to `database`:

```
dsn = "dbname='" + RDS_DBNAME + "' user='" + RDS_USERNAME + "' host='database' password='" + RDS_PASSWORD + "'"
dbConn = psycopg2.connect(dsn)
```

Besides that - you `with` looks strange. But that can be only my impression.

Comment: Is `RDS_DBNAME`, `RDS_USERNAME`, `RDS_PASSWORD` referring to what I defined inside `secrets/` directory?

Comment: @resolute - yes `RDS_DBNAME` is name of you database created by `schema.sql`, and to get there you need credentials, user from `dbUser.txt`, and password from `dbPassword.txt` :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Docker container may lack the `which` shell command.

`testing.postgresql` calls `testing.common.database.get_path_of`, which then executes the `which` command to locate the `initdb` program:

```
def get_path_of(name):
    if os.name == 'nt':
        which = 'where'
    else:
        which = 'which'
    try:
        path = subprocess.Popen([which, name],
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        if path:
            return path.rstrip().decode('utf-8')
        else:
            return None
    except Exception:
        return None
```

If `which` is missing, you can probably add it using a package manager. This worked on my CentOS-based container:

`yum install which`

Comment: yum install which does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

To use `testing.postgresql` you need access to postgresql server in your `myproject` Docker not just in the `database` Docker. The local temporary test database will connect to the other database to get data, but it still means you need a local instance of postgresql server inside the myproject.

In your `myproject/Dockerfile` just change the first `RUN` and add `postgresql` after `poppler-utils`.